# Role of TLB in Linux VM

Tags: linux, operating-system

Does linux make use of TLB when running as VM?

I wrote a C program to find 'Average access time per page' and found that with any number of frequent page access, the 'Average access time per page' is same.

For example,

With frequent access of 32 pages (10000000 times), its ~10 nano seconds.

With frequent access of 64 pages (10000000 times), its ~10 nano seconds.

With frequent access of 124 pages (10000000 times), its ~10 nano seconds.

With frequent access of 256 pages (10000000 times), its ~10 nano seconds.

With frequent access of 512 pages (10000000 times), its ~10 nano seconds.

and so on.

Does the above test reflect that linux does can not use TLB when running as a virtual machine and always goes to page table entry to get the translation for every 'virtual page number' to 'Physical page frame' for a process?

My machine details are:

[ ] uname -mpi

x86_64 x86_64 x86_64

[ ] getconf PAGE_SIZE

4096

[ ] uname -a

Linux VirtualBox 5.8.0-53-generic #60~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 6 09:52:46 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Thanks,

Comment: Are you running VirtualBox with hardware virtualization enabled or disabled? Note that (assuming hardware virtualization enabled) you'd want an unpredictable/un-prefetchable access pattern; for 4 KiB pages most CPUs have 1024 or more TLBs; and (if you don't prevent it) the OS may quietly give you 2 MiB large page/s instead of 512 small pages (so that you're only using one TLB entry and not 512 TLB entries).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, Hardware virtualisation is enabled. Even with 1024 pages used, it gives me the average page access time around 10 nano seconds, but with 2048 pages used, per page access time increases to 17 nano seconds. Which means, the size of virtualised TLB is something between 1024 to 2048 in my VM.